# Taylor Approximations to avoid loss of significance

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

I am supposed to use taylor approximations to avoid loss of significance for the following functions:

a) $f(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2x}$

b) $f(x)=\frac{log(1-x)+x*e^{x/2}}{x^3}$

and then find $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ for a) and b).

Here is the work I have done so far for each:

a) since $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...$ and $e^{-x}=1-x+\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+...$ , $\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2x}=\frac{1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...-1+x-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}-...}{2x}=\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+...=\sum_{n=3 odd}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$. Is this right? Is there a better way to put it? And how do I find $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$?

b) since $log(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}-...$ and $xe^{x/2}=x+x^2+\frac{x^3}{4(2!)}+\frac{x^4}{8(4!)}+...$ then $\frac{log(1-x)+x*e^{x/2}}{x^3}=\frac{-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}-...+x+x^2+\frac{x^3}{4(2!)}+\frac{x^4}{8(4!)}+...}{x^3}=\frac{\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^3}{4(2!)}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^4}{8(4!)}+...}{x^3}=\frac{-1}{3}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{x}{4}+\frac{x}{3!*2^3}-\frac{x^2}{5}+...=\sum_2^\infty \frac{x^{n-2}}{n+1}+\frac{x^{n-2}}{2^n*n!}$. Is this the right taylor expansion? Again, how do I find $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$?

Comment: You might check the impact of the signs in  $1+x+\cdots-1+x-\cdots$ on the cancelation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) it should be $\dfrac{1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...-1+x-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}-...}{2x}=1+\dfrac{x^2}{3!}+\dfrac{x^4}{5!}+...=\sum_{n= odd}^\infty \dfrac{x^{n-1}}{n!}$
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=1$ as all terms with $x$ just vanishes.

b) it should be $xe^{x/2}=x+x^2+\dfrac{x^3}{4(2!)}+\dfrac{x^4}{8(3!)}+\cdots$
so $\dfrac{\log(1-x)+xe^{x/2}}{x^3}=-\dfrac{5}{24}-\dfrac{11}{48}x-\dfrac{379}{1920}x^2-\cdots$ which has a limit of $-\dfrac5{24}$ at $x=0$

Answer (score 1):

For a, $$\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2x}=\frac{1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...-1+x-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}-...}{2x}=\frac{2x+2\frac {x^2}{3!}+2\frac {x^5}{5!}+2\frac {x^7}{7!}+\dots}{2x}=1+\frac {x^2}{3!}+\frac {x^4}{5!}+\frac {x^6}{7!}$$  Once you have divided out the $2x$ in the denominator, evaluating the limit is easy.

Comment: I think you lost the $x^2$ after the last equality.

Comment: @Henry:  yes, an edit got mixed up.  Fixed.  Thanks